# Some Ubuntu 18.04 pre-installed apps don't launch

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

Ever since moving from Windows to Ubuntu the experience has been pleasant. I don't miss windows, at all. Ubuntu 18.04 was my first choice.

However some pre-installed apps like Calculator, Characters, System Monitor and  System Logs do not start at all and I don't get an error. I usually delete them and install the same app but with a higher rating (stars) in the software centre. Has anyone experienced this and what could be the cause?

I unfortunately do not have logs. But the problem can be replicated by following these steps:

1. Downloading the official ISO from ubuntu.com
2. Using `mksub` to create a persistent live USB
3. Booting from said USB and attempting to open the apps mentioned above.

Edit: 23 Oct 2019

I used these commands to install mksub.

sudo add-apt-repository universe

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi

I did not use a terminal to create the live usb with persistence. I used guidus. This was done from an ubuntu live disk created using Unetbootin on windows.

Comment: What if you run these apps from terminal? What output do you get?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH` in Terminal?

Comment: Please click [edit] and add the specific steps of item 2; what commands did you use with mkusb to create a persistent LiveUSB?

Comment: @K7AAY Please put a line-break while editing so that the list renders correctly.

Answer (score 3):

There is something common about the applications you mentioned, viz. *Calculator*, *Characters*, *System Monitor* and *System Logs*, they are all pre-installed as [snap applications](https://snapcraft.io/docs/getting-started) instead of in the traditional way (from `.deb` packages via `dpkg`/`apt`). Snap packages are deployed by a package management system called '*snappy*' built by Canonical Ltd.

Since you are having this trouble with these specific applications and the fact that the following fixes the issue

> I usually delete them and install the same app but with a higher rating (stars) in the software centre.

("*the same app but with a higher rating (stars)*" is the almost always, if not always, the traditional counterpart of a snap application in the Software centre, snap applications tend to show various issues due to the way they're deployed and their restrictive security features), it is most likely an issue with snaps on your system. Since there is no technical detail provided, it's hard to say what exactly the problem is. It can be any of various possible reasons, e.g. `snapd` is not installed or corrupted, your `PATH` is not set up properly for snaps etc.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is the download of the official ISO for Ubuntu 18.04. Downloads can, and do, get corrupted in transit, which is why Canonical suggests [verifying the ISO with a checksum comparison](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu).

When I use the open source [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) Windows LiveUSB generator, I create a persistent LiveUSB which works AOK for [Ubuntu 19.10](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=US&version=19.10&architecture=amd64) and gives me Calculator, Characters, System Monitors, and System Logs on both the installed system, as well as when I run from the LiveUSB. Try Rufus as per this [Ubuntu official tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1) and use [19.10](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=US&version=19.10&architecture=amd64).